# Pay if quitting a new job

Tags: salary, new-job, resignation, canada

I worked 3 days at a new job, and then I had to call in and quit, as my daughter ended ill in another city, and I went there. Do they have to pay me?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference put please include your country.

Comment: Canada, Ontario

Comment: Are you supposed to give notice to this job? Did you give notice?

Comment: "Do they have to pay me?"  That depends on what's written in your contract.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they would have to pay you in almost all developed countries in the world.

You've essentially left (very early) during your probationary period, so the company would have to pay you in full for all the days you have worked thus far, and then terminate your employment contract.

Comment: I did not have a contract. I left after 3 days, due to my child being ill.

Comment: @JackieR Eh? I get you left after 3 days, but you didn't sign any kind of paperwork etc. agreeing what your salary would be before you started work?!

Comment: I know how much the pay was, as it was stated in the ad. That having been said, it was never brought up! I signed tax forms, and other paperwork, I read carefully, it said nothing about probation period. This is fairly common in sales.

Comment: +1 This answer is very much correct. The fact that you didn't sign a contract in Canada is irrelevant, you guys agreed upon a rate (which is a oral agreement 
 and is enforceable under Canadian Law), they even advertised it as such. You filled out the appropriate tax forms and supplied them with labour. All of which means you are entitled to your wage for 3 days (less CPP, EI and other deductions of course). That said, you will have more direct answers if you look up the Ontario Labour Act - it will be detailed there.

Comment: @berry120 , in Canada and the US it is quite common to not have any paperwork about a job agreement. My company has over 60k employees, and we don't do any paperwork - it is 'employment at will' from both sides. That depends on the state of course.